# Question on variables, functions and the logic behind them?

Tags: javascript, function, object, variables

it's been awhile since I've been on here.

I'm following a tutorial on JavaScript text base adventures. Very basic tutorial. I have a function to change the rooms. I understand the logic behind it and it works.

It doesn't give me errors until I get to the goInside();

```
property 'description' of undefined
    at goInside (core.js:58)
    at playerInput (core.js:94)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (core.js:114)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
goInside @ core.js:58
playerInput @ core.js:94
(anonymous) @ core.js:114
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3


function changeRoom(dir) {
    if (rooms[currentRoom].directions[dir] !== undefined) {
        currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom].directions[dir]
        $('#game-text').append("<p>" + rooms[currentRoom].description + "</p>");
    } else {
        $('#game-text').append("<p>You cannot go that way!</p>");
    }
}
```

Here's the room variable which took me a minute to understand the format. I added buildings as an option that acts just like the directions would.

```
var rooms = {
    "start": {
      "description": "You are in Town waiting for something to happen",

      "details": "You notice a house and a shop. Should you explore?",

      "directions": {
        "north": "bridge",
        "west": "clearing"
      },

      "buildings": {
        "shop": "shop",
        "house": "house"
      },

      "items": ["water", "stick"],

      "minlvl": "1",
    },
```

The current room is start. You can type 'go north'. and it'll change the rooms fine. But what if I wanted more than 4 different ways to go? I thought this might work but can't figure out where I went wrong specifically. I reused the function but switched out the elements.

```
function goInside(building) {
    if (rooms[currentRoom].buildings[building] !== undefined) {
        currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom].buildings[building],
        $('#game-text').append("<p>" + rooms[currentRoom].description + "</p>");
    } else {
        $('#game-text').append("<p>You cannot go that way!</p>");
    }
}
```

Not looking for someone to program for me just explaining the logic that I might be missing. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit.

Looking into your solution I used the if statement and I'm still getting the error below. I don't understand because the changeRooms works fine to display the description and the goInside is a copy of changeRooms.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
    at goInside (core.js:58)
    at playerInput (core.js:94)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (core.js:114)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
goInside @ core.js:58
playerInput @ core.js:94
(anonymous) @ core.js:114
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
```

Line 58

```
$('#game-text').append("<p>" + rooms[currentRoom].description + "</p>");
```

Line 94 is the goInside function

```
case "explore":

            var building = input.split(" ")[1];
            goInside(building);
            break;
```

Comment: The code looks fine, what's wrong with it? Do you have rooms named `shop` and `house`?

Comment: `currentRoom` has to be a property in the `rooms` object.

Comment: I have those rooms as well as the other maps.
Im getting this error [code]core.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read

Comment: Do all your rooms have a `buildings` property?

Comment: Add the full error message to the question, not a comment.

Comment: Which line is line 58?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward hint as to what is wrong comes from the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined`. Looking at where you do try to read `description`:

```
 $('#game-text').append("<p>" + rooms[currentRoom].description + "</p>");
```

Thus, `rooms[currentRoom]` returns `undefined`. One plausible explanation is that if you're trying to enter e.g. "shop", yet there is no `rooms['shop']` defined. Make sure you have a room defined for "shop", i.e.

```
rooms = {
  "shop": {
    // definition similar to "start" etc.
  }
  // ... the rest of the rooms
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all rooms have a `buildings` property. If there are no other buildings you can go to from that room, the property should be an empty object, e.g.

```
"buildings": {},
```

Otherwise, you get an error trying to access `rooms[currentRoom].buildings[building]`. Even though you're testing whether this is defined, it can't index an object with `[building]` if there's no object there to begin with.

Or you need to make the `goInside()` function check for this first.

```
function goInside(building) {
    if (rooms[currentRoom].buildings && rooms[currentRoom].buildings[building]) {
        currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom].buildings[building],
        $('#game-text').append("<p>" + rooms[currentRoom].description + "</p>");
    } else {
        $('#game-text').append("<p>You cannot go that way!</p>");
    }
}
```